Is the HSK7-9 reading section easier than the HSK6 reading section?
I took the Chinese HSK6 exam about 5 days ago, and am mulling over taking the HSK7-9.  In comparing the reading sections of these two exams, we find:

HSK6: 50 questions in 50 minutes.

10 语病 "faulty wording" questions (multiple choice)
10 fill-in-the-blank (words) questions (multiple choice)
2 x 5 fill-in-the-blank (clauses) questions (5 options to be put in order)
4 x 5 read an article and choose the correct answer (multiple choice)



HSK7-9 (source; see also the mock exam): 47 questions in 60 minutes.

28 read an article and choose the correct answer (multiple choice; different question styles)
1 x 5 arrange the paragraphs in order
14 read an article and answer a question (typing)


(Note that the current HSK6 uses the 2.0 standards, and the current HSK7-9 uses the 3.0 standards.)
So you have a whopping 10 extra minutes on the HSK7-9 exam, there's three fewer questions, and there's no dreaded 语病 "faulty wording" section.  This makes me feel like the HSK7-9 reading section is substantially easier than the HSK6 reading section.  Of course, I haven't actually taken the exam myself, so there may be more to the story, e.g., harder reading materials.
Question: Is the HSK7-9 reading section easier than the HSK6 reading section?
I'd be interested in hearing from people who have taken both exams.
